# Can you post a GIF to Screenshot of the Week?

Tags: discussion, screenshot-of-the-week, meta

Are GIF files allowed as submissions for screenshot(s) of the 2 weeks?

Answer (score 5):

The image format is probably not too important, but please do not post an animation. It is bad for accessibility and mobile data plans and just plain annoying to have something constantly loop in the sidebar.

Comment: The (mobile) data is a good point. I know a friend who told me he has to buy the gigs monthly, and even 1 gig/month is expensive for him, where he lives. I've been so used to how abundant the Internet is where I live, that I actually forget not everyone is lucky enough to have good coverage.